# Dynamic category list on mega menu

Tags: magento2.3, megamenu

How do I list categories dynamically on Magentech Megamenu? Currently, I can only create static items then drag-drop them to other items to make their children. Is it possible for the mega menu to create a dynamic category list?

Magentech Mega Menu 3.2.0,
Magento 2.3

Comment: Magentech Megamenu ?? 
U are talking about an Extension ! 
I think, this's impossible to support for you.
Should contact Magentech :))

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm not asking for module alteration or modding. I just want to know how do I make it dynamic from mega menu module on admin dashboard or is it even possible. And yes I wrote ticket yesterday and still no reply